# PHP code updating all records instead of updating by id

Tags: php, html

My code updates all the records in my article table instead of updating by id. Here is my code. I'm very new to php so I will really appreciate any help at all. Thanks guys...

```
<div class="modal fade" id="active-id<?php echo $id;?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel8" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-wrapper">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header bg-green">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel8">Article Title: <?php echo $article_title?></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Are you sure you want to activate this article?</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <form method='post' role='form'>
                                <button type='submit' name='active_yes' class='btn btn-success'>Yes</button>
                                <button type='button' class='btn btn-success' data-dismiss='modal'>No</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php

                    if (isset($_POST['active_yes'])){

                        if ($post_active == "No") {
                            $sql = "UPDATE `articles` SET `post_active` = '1' WHERE `articles`.`id` = $id;";

                            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Article has been activated successfully and is currently live on the website.')</script>";
                            } else {
                                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Cannot activate article now. Please Try Again Later!')</script>";
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What a bad place for checking and using `$_POST` data, but, where is `$id` defined after the form is submitted? Also extends this `if($post_active == "No" && $id>0)` to really only update if a number id is given.

Answer (score 0):

$sql = "UPDATE `articles` SET `post_active` = '1' WHERE `articles`.`id` = {$id}";

That's a little problem with the query.

The php code is also wrong because when you submit the form the page tends to reload due to your code strategy.
Therefore the $id is lost and the php segment will run without an $id so all data in the table will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

First check to see what value is in the `$id` variable by using echo. It might be the reason why it is updating all since it might not be passed.

Also try editing your form to include your `$id` variable so that your php script can read it directly from the form;

```
<form method='post' role='form' action="#">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
   <button type='submit' name='active_yes' class='btn btn-success'>Yes</button>
   <button type='button' class='btn btn-success' data-dismiss='modal'>No</button>
 </form>
```

And your `$sql` variable to;

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$sql = "UPDATE `articles` SET `post_active` = '1' WHERE `articles`.`id` = $id";
```

Let me know if it helps or if you come across any problem.